# How do i make a continue button? Python, tkinter

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter, widget, tkinter-entry

I want to make a button in my widget that when I press it, it proceeds to the next lines of code, and closes the existing widget of where the button is.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
Label(root, text = "Childs First name").grid(row = 0, sticky = W)
Label(root, text = "Childs Surname").grid(row = 1, sticky = W)
Label(root, text = "Childs Year of Birth").grid(row = 2, sticky = W)
Label(root, text = "Childs Month of Birth").grid(row = 3, sticky = W)
Label(root, text = "Childs Day of Birth").grid(row = 4, sticky = W)

Fname = Entry(root)
Sname = Entry(root)
x = Entry(root)
y = Entry(root)
z = Entry(root)


Fname.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
Sname.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
x.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
y.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
z.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

button1 = Button(root, text = "Quit", command = root.quit, bg = "Grey", fg =     "White", width = 12).grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = W)


def save():
Fname_value = Fname.get()
Sname_value = Sname.get()
x_value = x.get()
y_value = y.get()
z_value = z.get()

save()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you have any code yet? What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: This just isn't how GUI Programming works. You should probably read through a tutorial about event based programming. In your case, typically you would create a "save" button that calls `save`.

Comment: However is it possible o make a continue button

Comment: You can put any text you want on a button, but it won't do anything until you learn how to make it do something. As Bryan says, you need to read some tkinter tutorials to get a general concept of how this kind of programming works.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this late answer. To make a 'continue' button:

```
continue_button = tk.Button(frame,text='continue',command=func)
continue_button.config(width=width_continue_button)
# set the coordinates as you want. here 2,6 for the example
continue_button.grid(row=2,column=6,padx=width_continue_grid)
```

then you have to write the function 'func' to fulfill your needs.

hope this helps